How to evaluate nested boolean/logical expressions in Python?
I'm working on a complex rule parser that has the following properties:

A space character separates rules
A "+" character indicates an "AND" operator
A "," character indicates an "OR" operator
A "-" indicates an optional element
Tokens in parenthesis should be evaluated together

I'm able to do simple rules but having trouble evaluating complex rules in nested parenthesis.
Here's nested rule definition I'm trying to evaluate:
definition = '((K00925 K00625),K01895) (K00193+K00197+K00194) (K00577+K00578+K00579+K00580+K00581-K00582-K00583+K00584) (K00399+K00401+K00402) (K22480+K22481+K22482,K03388+K03389+K03390,K08264+K08265,K03388+K03389+K03390+K14127+(K14126+K14128,K22516+K00125))'


Rule 1: ((K00925 K00625),K01895)

This one is kind of tricky.  Basically this rule either K00925 then separately K00625 OR just K01895 alone.  Since it's all within a parenthesis set then that translates to  (K00925 & K00625) OR K01895 as indicated by "," character.


Rule 2: (K00193+K00197+K00194)

All 3 items must be present as indicated by "+" sign


Rule 3: (K00577+K00578+K00579+K00580+K00581-K00582-K00583+K00584)

Everything except K00582 and K00583 because they are prefixed by "-" characters and when "+" is present then all items must be present


Rule 4: (K00399+K00401+K00402)

All 3 items must be present as indicated by "+" sign


Rule 5: (K22480+K22481+K22482,K03388+K03389+K03390,K08264+K08265,K03388+K03389+K03390+K14127+(K14126+K14128,K22516+K00125))

This is simpler than it looks. Either  (K22480+K22481+K22482) OR (K03388+K03389+K03390).  For the last subrule, it is K08264+K08265,K03388+K03389+K03390+K14127+(Either K14126+K14128 OR K22516+K00125))



Here's the code I have that is almost correct:
import re

def rule_splitter(rule: str, split_characters: set = {"+", "-", ",", "(", ")", " "}) -> set:
    """
    Split rule by characters.

    Args:
        rule (str): Boolean logical string.
        split_characters (list): List of characters to split in rule.

    Returns:
        set: Unique tokens in a rule.
    """
    rule_decomposed = str(rule)
    if split_characters:
        for character in split_characters:
            character = character.strip()
            if character:
                rule_decomposed = rule_decomposed.replace(character, " ")
    unique_tokens = set(filter(bool, rule_decomposed.split()))
    return unique_tokens

def find_rules(definition: str) -> list:
    """
    Find and extract rules from the definition string.

    Args:
        definition (str): Complex boolean logical string with multiple rules.

    Returns:
        list: List of extracted rules as strings.
    """
    rules = []
    stack = []
    current_rule = ""
    outside_rule = ""

    for char in definition:
        if char == '(':
            if stack:
                current_rule += char
            if outside_rule.strip():
                rules.append(outside_rule.strip())
                outside_rule = ""
            stack.append(char)
        elif char == ')':
            stack.pop()
            if stack:
                current_rule += char
            else:
                current_rule = f"({current_rule.strip()})"
                rules.append(current_rule)
                current_rule = ""
        else:
            if stack:
                current_rule += char
            else:
                outside_rule += char

    # Add any remaining outside_rule at the end of the loop
    if outside_rule.strip():
        rules.append(outside_rule.strip())

    return rules

def evaluate_rule(rule: str, tokens: set, replace={"+": " and ", ",": " or "}) -> bool:
    """
    Evaluate a string of boolean logicals.

    Args:
        rule (str): Boolean logical string.
        tokens (set): List of tokens in rule.
        replace (dict, optional): Replace boolean characters. Defaults to {"+":" and ", "," : " or "}.

    Returns:
        bool: Evaluated rule.
    """
    # Handle optional tokens prefixed by '-'
    rule = re.sub(r'-\w+', '', rule)

    # Replace characters for standard logical formatting
    if replace:
        for character_before, character_after in replace.items():
            rule = rule.replace(character_before, character_after)

    # Split the rule into individual symbols
    unique_symbols = rule_splitter(rule, replace.values())

    # Create a dictionary with the presence of each symbol in the tokens
    token_to_bool = {sym: (sym in tokens) for sym in unique_symbols}

    # Parse and evaluate the rule using a recursive descent parser
    def parse_expression(expression: str) -> bool:
        expression = expression.strip()
        
        # Handle nested expressions
        if expression.startswith('(') and expression.endswith(')'):
            return parse_expression(expression[1:-1])

        # Evaluate 'OR' conditions
        if ' or ' in expression:
            parts = expression.split(' or ')
            return any(parse_expression(part) for part in parts)
        
        # Evaluate 'AND' conditions
        elif ' and ' in expression:
            parts = expression.split(' and ')
            return all(parse_expression(part) for part in parts)
        
        # Evaluate individual token presence
        else:
            return token_to_bool.get(expression.strip(), False)

    return parse_expression(rule)

def evaluate_definition(definition: str, tokens: set) -> dict:
    """
    Evaluate a complex definition string involving multiple rules.

    Args:
        definition (str): Complex boolean logical string with multiple rules.
        tokens (set): Set of tokens to check against the rules.

    Returns:
        dict: Dictionary with each rule and its evaluated result.
    """
    # Extract individual rules from the definition
    rules = find_rules(definition)
    
    # Evaluate each rule
    rule_results = {}
    for rule in rules:
        try:
            cleaned_rule = rule[1:-1] if rule.startswith('(') and rule.endswith(')') else rule  # Remove outer parentheses if they exist
            result = evaluate_rule(cleaned_rule, tokens)
        except SyntaxError:
            # Handle syntax errors from eval() due to incorrect formatting
            result = False
        rule_results[rule] = result
    
    return rule_results

# Example usage
definition = '((K00925 K00625),K01895) (K00193+K00197+K00194) (K00577+K00578+K00579+K00580+K00581-K00582-K00583+K00584) (K00399+K00401+K00402) (K22480+K22481+K22482,K03388+K03389+K03390,K08264+K08265,K03388+K03389+K03390+K14127+(K14126+K14128,K22516+K00125))'
tokens = {
    'K00925',
    'K00625',
    # 'K01895',
    'K00193',
    'K00197',
    'K00194',
    'K00577',
    'K00578',
    'K00579',
    'K00580',
    'K00581',
    # 'K00582',
    'K00584',
    'K00399',
    'K00401',
    'K00402',
    'K22480',
    # 'K22481',
    # 'K22482',
    'K03388',
    'K03389',
    'K03390',
    # 'K08264',
    # 'K08265',
    'K14127',
    'K14126',
    'K14128',
    'K22516',
    # 'K00125'
}

result = evaluate_definition(definition, tokens)
# result
# {'((K00925 K00625),K01895)': False,
#  '(K00193+K00197+K00194)': True,
#  '(K00577+K00578+K00579+K00580+K00581-K00582-K00583+K00584)': True,
#  '(K00399+K00401+K00402)': True,
#  '(K22480+K22481+K22482,K03388+K03389+K03390,K08264+K08265,K03388+K03389+K03390+K14127+(K14126+K14128,K22516+K00125))': True}


Note that the implementation is splitting the first rule.
Here is the following output I'm expecting:
{
    '(K00925 K00625),K01895)':True, # Note this is True because of `K00925` and `K00625` together (b/c the parenthesis) OR K01895 being present
    '(K00193+K00197+K00194)':True,
    '(K00577+K00578+K00579+K00580+K00581-K00582-K00583+K00584)':True, # This is missing optional tokens
    '(K00399+K00401+K00402)':True,
    '(K22480+K22481+K22482,K03388+K03389+K03390,K08264+K08265,K03388+K03389+K03390+K14127+(K14126+K14128,K22516+K00125)':True, # This combination allows for {K03388, K03389, K03390, K14127} +{K14126+K14128}
}


Here's a graphical representation of the information flow for this complex rule definition:

It should also be able to handle this rule:
rule_edge_case='((K00134,K00150) K00927,K11389)' with the following query tokens: tokens = {     'K00134',       'K00927'}.  This should be True because either (K00134 OR K00150) with K00927 are present which is sufficient.
Edit 1: I had an error before and the last rule was actually True and not False.
Edit 2: I've changed "items" to "tokens" and modified which tokens are used for evaluation to capture better edge cases.

"K00925 then separately K00625"  This appears to be an AND.  How is it different?

A second idea is in rules = re.findall(r'\([^\)]+\)', definition).  They say, that when you use a regular expression to solve a problem, then you have two problems.  Perhaps you don't have a background in parsers, or need a referesher, but I think that a recursive decent parser may give you simpler sub-problems (nested) that iterating over all re-matching paren-pairs does.

@VoNWooDSoN that's why it's tricky. Check out the graph representation at the bottom of the post.  There is K00925 which is a simple rule, then if that is successful it goes to K00625, then if that's successful it goes to K00193.  Alternatively, the flow through the network can go straight to K00193 if K01895 is present.  So theoretically they are 2 separate rules but in reality they can be treated as an "&" operator in this case for simplicity.

A great tool for this job would be a proper parser for expression grammars. I'm using parsimonious for this answer, which allows you to define a BNF or eBNF like syntax for your grammar, to assist with decoding your DSL.

edit I updated the grammar to check the or "," operator before checking for the rule break operator " ". This also means you check for the maybe_or in the brace_expression definition, rather than for the rules definition.

Defining the grammar
Given the rules, you've defined a few operators with different precedence.

Break all values by the or operator ","
Break all top level items by the rules " "
Break all values by the and operator "+" or ignore operator "-"

"+" and "-" have the same precedence


Values may be defined in braces "(...)"

These are to be recursively parsed by referencing the root definition.



Given these rules, here's how you can define a grammar.
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar


grammar = Grammar(
    """
    maybe_or = (maybe_rule or+) / maybe_rule
    or = "," maybe_rule

    maybe_rule = (maybe_and rule+) / maybe_and
    rule = " " maybe_and

    maybe_and = (expression and+) / expression
    and = and_op expression
    and_op = "+" / "-"

    expression = brace_expression / variable
    brace_expression = "(" maybe_or ")"

    variable = ~r"[A-Z0-9]+"
    """
)

In this example, I've made explicit steps that allow following the operator precedence in the grammar. Depending on your descent parser, you may wish to order differently. In the case of parsimonious, items are greedily captured, meaning we want to evaluate the long form of the definition first.
Defining containers
Now that we have a grammar, we can construct containers to represent its hierarchy. We'll want to be able to test against the items set by evaluating each container against its children.
At this point we can consider which of the operators need to be defined by separate containers. The and-operation "+" and rules operator " " have the same boolean evaluation, so we can combine them to a single And class. Other containers would be Or, Ignored and Var to represent the bool var codename.
We'll also benefit from a str repr to see whats going on in the case of errors, which we can use to dump out a normalized version of the expression.
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Protocol


class Matcher(Protocol):
    def matches(self, variables: List[str]) -> bool:
        pass

@dataclass
class Var:
    value: str

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    def matches(self, variables: List[str]) -> bool:
        return self.value in variables

@dataclass
class Ignored:
    value: Matcher

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.value}?"

    def matches(self, variables: List[str]) -> bool:
        return True

@dataclass
class And:
    values: List[Matcher]

    def __str__(self):
        return "(" + "+".join(map(str, self.values))  + ")"

    def matches(self, variables: List[str]) -> bool:
        return all(v.matches(variables) for v in self.values)

@dataclass
class Or:
    values: List[Matcher]

    def __str__(self):
        return "(" + ",".join(map(str, self.values)) + ")"

    def matches(self, variables: List[str]) -> bool:
        return any(v.matches(variables) for v in self.values)

Parsing the grammar
With a grammar and a set of containers we can now begin to unpack the statement. We can use the NodeVistor class from parsimonious for this. Each definition in the grammar can be given its own handler method to use while unpacking values.
You'll want to add lots of test cases for this class, as the parsing logic used is highly dependent on the grammar being evaluated. I've found if the grammar is logical, so will the decoder methods be on the NodeVistor implementation.
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor


class Visitor(NodeVisitor):
    def visit_maybe_rule(self, node, visited_children):
        # If there are multiple rules, combine them.

        children, *_ = visited_children
        if isinstance(children, list):
            return And([children[0], *children[1]])
        return children

    def visit_rule(self, node, visited_children):
        # Strip out the " " rule operator child token

        return visited_children[1]

    def visit_maybe_or(self, node, visited_children):
        # If there are multiple or values, combine them.

        children, *_ = visited_children
        if isinstance(children, list):
            return Or([children[0], *children[1]])
        return children

    def visit_or(self, node, visited_children):
        # Strip out the "," or operator child token

        return visited_children[1]

    def visit_maybe_and(self, node, visited_children):
        # If there are multiple and values, combine them.

        children, *_ = visited_children
        if isinstance(children, list):
            return And([children[0], *children[1]])
        return children

    def visit_and(self, node, visited_children):
        # Strip out the operator child token, and
        # handle the case where we ignore values.

        if visited_children[0] == "-":
            return Ignored(visited_children[1])
        return visited_children[1]

    def visit_and_op(self, node, visited_children):
        # get the text of the operator.

        return node.text

    def visit_expression(self, node, visited_children):
        # expressions only have one item

        return visited_children[0]

    def visit_brace_expression(self, node, visited_children):
        # Strip out the "(" opening and ")" closing braces

        return visited_children[1]

    def visit_variable(self, node, visited_children):
        # Parse the variable name

        return Var(node.text)

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        # Catchall response.

        return visited_children or node

Testing
Following your example set, we can see each output and how it is being evaluated quite clearly.
items = {
    'K00925', 'K00193', 'K00197', 'K00194', 'K00577', 'K00578', 'K00579', 'K00580', 'K00581',
    'K00582', 'K00584', 'K00399', 'K00401', 'K00402', 'K22480', 'K22481', 'K22482', 'K03388',
    'K03389', 'K03390', 'K08264', 'K08265', 'K14127', 'K14126', 'K22516',
}

definitions = [
    "((K00925 K00625),K01895)",
    "(K00193+K00197+K00194)",
    "(K00577+K00578+K00579+K00580+K00581-K00582-K00583+K00584)",
    "(K00399+K00401+K00402)",
    "(K22480+K22481+K22482,K03388+K03389+K03390,K08264+K08265,K03388+K03389+K03390+K14127+(K14126+K14128,K22516+K00125))",
    "((K00134,K00150) K00927,K11389)",
]

for definition in definitions:
    tree = grammar.parse(definition)
    val = Visitor().visit(tree)
    print(f"Test: {definition}")
    print(f"Parsed as: {val}")
    print(f"Result: {val.matches(items)}")
    print()

Which outputs as expected:
Test: ((K00925 K00625),K01895)
Parsed as: ((K00925+K00625),K01895)
Result: False

Test: (K00193+K00197+K00194)
Parsed as: (K00193+K00197+K00194)
Result: True

Test: (K00577+K00578+K00579+K00580 K00581-K00582-K00583+K00584)
Parsed as: ((K00577+K00578+K00579+K00580)+(K00581+K00582?+K00583?+K00584))
Result: True

Test: (K00399+K00401+K00402)
Parsed as: (K00399+K00401+K00402)
Result: True

Test: (K22480+K22481+K22482,K03388+K03389+K03390,K08264+K08265,K03388+K03389+K03390+K14127+(K14126+K14128,K22516+K00125))
Parsed as: ((K22480+K22481+K22482),(K03388+K03389+K03390),(K08264+K08265),(K03388+K03389+K03390+K14127+((K14126+K14128),(K22516+K00125))))
Result: True

Test: ((K00134,K00150) K00927,K11389)
Parsed as: (((K00134,K00150)+K00927),K11389)
Result: False


Sorry for the delay.  I'm trying to test this out but unable to find the Protocol class in the package.  How can I load this into my environment?

@O.rka Should be from the typing module from typing import Protocol. See https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/ It allows creating a contract for your classes without having to inherit, which avoids a lot of nastiness at runtime, while still allowing for rich type-checking.

Thank you @flakes I got it to run. I found an edge case that isn't being parsed correctly: '((K00134,K00150) K00927,K11389)' where Parsed as: ((K00134,K00150)+(K00927,K11389)) but it should be Parsed as: ((K00134,K00150)+K00927,K11389))

@O.rka You'll need to define the operator precedence more concretely for me to say further. In your original question, you defined the "rules" as the first option for splitting, so I took that to mean highest precedence. Take a look at the grammar and see how your phrase splits apart as you flow down through it. The higher the rule, the higher the precedence following this order. Take a stab at re-constructing the grammar if you want to change the precedence of operations. Even if you don't use a library, writing the grammar down acts as great documentation to follow while writing your parser.

I'll try to modify tomorrow and will give it another try.  This seems to be the most robust way.  tbh it's a bit of a steep learning curve but seems worthwhile to learn.

@O.rka I updated the answer to place or as higher precedence than rules, and added in your new test-case.

Also note, given the new ordering, it seems like " " and "+" operators effectively produce the same results. You could choose to combine " "  into the and definition to further reduce the grammar.

Thank you for the modification.  I've tested a bunch of different examples and it's all checking out.  I just marked as correct and will issue the bounty once it's available.  Where can I learn more about this type of parsing and grammar?

@O.rka Great to hear! I studied this subject during university, but I wouldn't say I'm an expert! If you really want to go down the rabbit hole, "the dragon book" (Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools) is awesome. That book is about creating programming languages, but parsing a grammar is a huge section of it. This post also lists some great resources!

Have a try on this my bro:
import re
import json


class RuleParser:
    def __init__(self, definition, present_tokens):
        self.definition = definition
        self.present_tokens = set(present_tokens)

    def parse_and_evaluate(self):
        rules = self._extract_rules(self.definition)
        return {rule: self._evaluate_rule(rule) for rule in rules}

    def _extract_rules(self, definition):
        rules = []
        stack = []
        current_rule = ""
        for char in definition:
            if char == "(":
                stack.append(char)
                current_rule += char
            elif char == ")":
                stack.pop()
                current_rule += char
                if not stack:  # If we've closed all open parentheses
                    rules.append(current_rule)
                    current_rule = ""
            elif not stack:  # If we're not inside any parentheses
                if char.strip():  # If it's not just whitespace
                    current_rule = ""  # Start a new rule
            else:
                current_rule += char
        return rules

    def _evaluate_rule(self, rule):
        # Remove the outermost parentheses
        return self._evaluate_expression(rule[1:-1])

    def _evaluate_expression(self, expr):
        print(f"Evaluating expression: {expr}")
        if "," in expr:
            parts = self._split_keeping_brackets(expr)
            print(f"Split parts: {parts}")
            return any(self._evaluate_subexpression(part.strip()) for part in parts)
        else:
            return self._evaluate_subexpression(expr)
        
    def _evaluate_subexpression(self, expr):
        if "+" in expr:
            parts = expr.split("+")
            for part in parts:
                part = part.strip()
                if "-" in part:
                    sub_parts = part.split("-")
                    if not self._evaluate_token(sub_parts[0]):
                        return False
                    if any(self._evaluate_token(token) for token in sub_parts[1:]):
                        return False
                elif not self._evaluate_token(part):
                    return False
            return True
        else:
            return all(self._evaluate_token(token.strip()) for token in expr.split())
    def _evaluate_token(self, token):
        if token.startswith("(") and token.endswith(")"):
            return self._evaluate_expression(token[1:-1])
        else:
            return token in self.present_tokens

    def _split_keeping_brackets(self, expr):
        result = []
        current = []
        depth = 0
        for char in expr:
            if char == "(":
                depth += 1
            elif char == ")":
                depth -= 1
            elif char == "," and depth == 0:
                result.append("".join(current))
                current = []
                continue
            current.append(char)
        if current:
            result.append("".join(current))
        return result


# 使用示例
definition = "((K00925 K00625),K01895) (K00193+K00197+K00194) (K00577+K00578+K00579+K00580+K00581-K00582-K00583+K00584) (K00399+K00401+K00402) (K22480+K22481+K22482,K03388+K03389+K03390,K08264+K08265,K03388+K03389+K03390+K14127+(K14126+K14128,K22516+K00125))"



present_tokens = [
    'K00925', 
   'K00625', 
    'K01895', 
    'K00193', 
    'K00197', 
    'K00194', 
    'K00577', 
    'K00578', 
    'K00579', 
    'K00580', 
    'K00581', 
    'K00582', 
    'K00584', 
    'K00399', 
    'K00401', 
    'K00402', 
#    'K22480', 
#    'K22481', 
#    'K22482', 
#     'K03388', 
#    'K03389', 
#    'K03390', 
#    'K08264', 
#    'K08265',
#    'K14127', 
#    'K14126', 
#    'K14128', 
#    'K22516', 
#    'K00125'
]
parser = RuleParser(definition, present_tokens)
result = parser.parse_and_evaluate()

print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))





When I try this: present_tokens = {     'K00925',     # 'K00625',     # 'K01895',     'K00193',     'K00197',     'K00194',     'K00577',     'K00578',     'K00579',     'K00580',     'K00581',     'K00582',     'K00584',     'K00399',     'K00401',     'K00402',     # 'K22480',     # 'K22481',     # 'K22482',     # 'K03388',     # 'K03389',     # 'K03390',     # 'K08264',     # 'K08265',     # 'K14127',     # 'K14126',     # 'K14128',     # 'K22516',     # 'K00125' }  I get RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

I fixed my code to avoid recursion when a rule met no any rule code.

You can use 2 steps to solve this:

Extract the top-level rules from the definition
For each rule, apply a transformation to it and call eval()

Here is a possible implementation:
import re

def extract_rules(definition):
    rules = []
    i = 0
    parens = 0
    # Find the spaces located outside parentheses
    for j, c in enumerate(definition):
        if c == '(':
            parens += 1
        elif c == ')':
            parens -= 1
        elif c == ' ' and parens == 0:
            rules.append(definition[i:j])
            i = j + 1
    rules.append(definition[i:])
    return rules

def evaluate_rule(rule, tokens):

    # Extract the variables contained in the rule and assign a boolean value to them
    var_names = set(re.findall(r'\w+', rule))
    vars = {name: name in tokens for name in var_names}

    # Remove the optional variables
    rule = re.sub(r'-\w+', '', rule)

    # Replace the operators with the standard Python ones
    rule = rule.replace(' ', ' and ')
    rule = rule.replace('+', ' and ')
    rule = rule.replace(',', ' or ')

    # We are now ready to eval the string
    return eval(rule, vars)

def evaluate_definition(definition, tokens):
    rules = extract_rules(definition)
    return {rule: evaluate_rule(rule, tokens) for rule in rules}

Simple example:
definition = '(V1 V2),V3 V4'
tokens = {'V1', 'V2'}
print(evaluate_definition(definition, tokens))

Output:
{'(V1 V2),V3': True,
 'V4': False}

Complex example from the question:
definition = '((K00925 K00625),K01895) (K00193+K00197+K00194) (K00577+K00578+K00579+K00580+K00581-K00582-K00583+K00584) (K00399+K00401+K00402) (K22480+K22481+K22482,K03388+K03389+K03390,K08264+K08265,K03388+K03389+K03390+K14127+(K14126+K14128,K22516+K00125))'
tokens = {
    'K00925',
    'K00625',
    # 'K01895',
    'K00193',
    'K00197',
    'K00194',
    'K00577',
    'K00578',
    'K00579',
    'K00580',
    'K00581',
    # 'K00582',
    'K00584',
    'K00399',
    'K00401',
    'K00402',
    'K22480',
    # 'K22481',
    # 'K22482',
    'K03388',
    'K03389',
    'K03390',
    # 'K08264',
    # 'K08265',
    'K14127',
    'K14126',
    'K14128',
    'K22516',
    # 'K00125'
}
print(evaluate_definition(definition, tokens))

Output:
{'((K00925 K00625),K01895)': True,
 '(K00193+K00197+K00194)': True,
 '(K00577+K00578+K00579+K00580+K00581-K00582-K00583+K00584)': True,
 '(K00399+K00401+K00402)': True,
 '(K22480+K22481+K22482,K03388+K03389+K03390,K08264+K08265,K03388+K03389+K03390+K14127+(K14126+K14128,K22516+K00125))': True}


Not all " " are interpreted as "and".  The only reason V1 and V2 are interpreted as "and" in ((V1 V2),V3) is because they are inclosed in nested parentheses with an "or" statement.

@O.rka I have edited my answer.
